# Number of automorphisms of n-dimensional hypercube graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Hypercube graph definition from Wikipedia:

> In graph theory, the **hypercube graph** $Q_n $is the graph formed from the vertices and edges of an n-dimensional hypercube.

My teacher gave the number $2^n n!$ but I don't know how to compute it.
First I tried prove it by induction on $n$. Base case for $n=2$ is simple. However, I ran into some trouble for higher dimensions. It's really hard even to visualize 4-dimensional space.
Then I tried to prove it by the Stabilizer-Orbit theorem. Also failed for high dimensions.

This seems like a really elementary question. Need a little help.

Comment: You can decompose a $n$-dimensional hypercube into $2n$ copies of an $(n-1)$-dimensional hypercube, and then try to work out the automorphism inductively.

Comment: Does the definition you provided really help you to find, say, the edge set of $Q_5$? In order to give a proof, you really need a clear definition of the structure for which you are going to prove something. While this definition makes everyone know what you are talking about, I doubt it is very useful for a proof of given statement.

Comment: @M.Winter The definition in my assignment is even shorter than the Wikipedia version. My teacher never talked about hypercube in the sessions. So do you have any reference I can take a look at?

Comment: @xixumei Oh. Well, my favorite definition is choose $V=\{0,1\}^n$ as the set of all binary sequences of length $n$, and $\{v,w\}\in E$ if and only if the sequences $v$ and $w$ differ in exactly a single element.

Comment: @M.Winter This is a definition? I feel like it's more of an observation/property. I thought the Wikipedia version is the only definition of  hypercube. With this "definition", the problem I posted seems more straightforward.

Comment: @xixumei It is definitely a matter of taste. Yes you can call it an observation, but you can use this "observation" to give a definition which absolutely abandons the geometric view and allows you to formally talk about the graph detached from any other part of math. Otherwise you have to define what "vertices" and "edges" of the hypercube $[0,1]^n$ even mean, which is not straight forward but needs tools of convex geometry. However, I admit that depending on how formal you task is and final proof should be, your definition may be "good enough".

Comment: @xixumei I like this definition because it explicitly states the vertex and edge set.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you so much for your help! I’ll find more material to work on...

Comment: @xixumei I extended my answer a bit. I do not know if this helps you or you are looking for a geometric proof, but this is what I had in mind, along the lines of my definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an intuitive (non-rigorous) reasoning why the answer might be $2^nn!$.

Lets say your $n$-dimensional hypercube is given as the set $[0,1]^n$. An automorphism is a transformation of the cube after which it looks exactly like before. In the case of the hypercube, these transformations are all *rigid rotations* and *reflections* (this would need a proof when done rigirously).

So think about this hypercube as a small piece of [material of your choice] sitting in the corner of the positive [orthant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant) $\Bbb R^{n+}$. Now take it into your hand, rotate it a bit, and place it back into the corner. What could have changed? For example: the corner which touches the orthant's corner $(0,...,0)$ has changed. There are $2^n$ corners of the hypercube, so there are already $2^n$ choices which one to place there.

What other options do we have? Lets say it is the corner $v$ of the hypercube which gets placed in the orthant's corner after the transformation. There are $n$ edges of the hypercube which start in $v$. And now we have the option to place any of these edges on any of the orthant's axes. E.g. for a $3$D-cube,

\begin{align}
\text{place the hypercube's $x$-edge on the orthant's $y$-axis,}\\
\text{place the hypercube's $y$-edge on the orthant's $z$-axis,}\\
\text{place the hypercube's $z$-edge on the orthant's $x$-axis.}
\end{align}

Geometrically, this is a rotation of the $3$-cube. With rotations and reflections you can achieve any possible permutations of the $\{x,y,z\}$-edges onto the $\{x,y,z\}$-axes. This is still true in higher dimensions (but not obvious). Any permutation is possible and can be achieved by a series of rotations and reflections. So for any transformation which moves the corner $v$ into the orthant's origin, there are still $n!$ (that is the number of permutations) choices on how to place the edges on the axes. Together with the $2^n$ choices of the corner $v$ we have $2^nn!$ choices for the automorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**

Given a vertex $v\in V(Q_n)$. An automorphism of $Q_n$ is uniquely determined by the images of $v$ and all its neighbors $w\in N(v)$. Can you see why and how this gives $2^nn!$ ?

---

**Hint 2**

I assume the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph $Q_n=(V,E)$ is given by the vertex set $V=\{0,1\}^n$ of all binary sequences of length $n$, and $\{v,w\}\in E$ if and only if the two sequences $v$ and $w$ differ in exactly one element.

> **Theorem**. The automorphisms of $Q_n$ are exactly the maps $$v\mapsto (v\circ\sigma)\oplus s$$ for vertices $s\in V$ and permutations $\sigma:\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$. Here $\oplus$ denotes the element-wise XOR operation. Note that every vertex can be considered as a map $\{1,...,n\}\to\{0,1\}$, hence the concatenation $\circ$ is meaningful.

Try to prove this. First show that this map is indeed an automorphism. Then (and this might be the harder part) show that any automorphism is of this form, e.g. by showing that every automorphism has an inverse of this form.

Once you have achieved this, observe that there are $2^n$ vertices $s\in V$ and $n!$ permutations $\sigma$. This gives a total of $2^nn!$ automorphisms.

---

Still another way. Prove

> **Theorem**. Let $v\in V$ be a vertex in $Q_n$ and $N(v)$ its neighborhood. A vertex $w\in V$ is uniquely determined by its distances $d(w,u),u\in N(v)$.

You can use this to make **Hint 1** into a rigorous proof.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't so straightforward for me :(

Comment: Tell me, what do you know about the hypercube graph? What is the definition you are using? Even better: include everything which you are going to tell me into your post.